# How to save a large dict with tuples as keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have large dict which has 3-tuples of integers as keys. I would like to save it to disk so I can read it in quickly. Sadly it seems I can't save it as a JSON file (which would let me use a fast JSON module such as [orjson](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/)).  What are my options other than pickle?

A tiny example would be:

```
my_dict = {
(1, 2, 3): [4, 5, 6],
(4, 5, 6): [7, 8, 9],
(7, 8, 9): [10, 11, 12]
}
```

I have about 500,000 keys and each value list is of length 500.

I will make this data once and it will not be modified after it is made. `my_dict` will only ever be used as a lookup table

Comment: Could you please give some examples of input and output you expect?

Comment: Why not pickle? I don't think there's a standard serialization format for this.

Comment: @Barmar pickles are opaque when shared with others and a security risk to anyone using them.

Comment: What about a SQLite database, or if it's for a sciencey application maybe hdf5?

Comment: JSON is *not* how you would create large, fast database, even if you had valid keys. You want a database.

Comment: Also it helps to use numbers rather than "large".  E.g. do you mean millions of entries, billions, more, less?

Comment: @Simd, a few important questions that may help to find a solution: 1) how are those 3-int tuples made before being added as keys? 2) Is `my_dict` is only be used as a lookup table? 2) do `my_dict` keys (as tuples) are involved somewhere is any comparisons or containment checks like `(1,2,3) in my_dict.keys()`

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? Do you reject pickle only because it is opaque or also because it can execute arbitrary code, i.e. do you reject every format that could execute code?

Comment: @SamMason sqlite sounds very interesting. I have never used that

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the package `pprint`. This is a code saving the file as a Python module, which you can import either as module or just the dictionary object. This is the code.

```py
import pprint

my_dict = {
    (1, 2, 3): [4, 5, 6],
    (4, 5, 6): [7, 8, 9],
    (7, 8, 9): [10, 11, 12]
}

obj_str = pprint.pformat(my_dict, indent=4, compact=False)

message = f'my_dict = {obj_str}\n'

with open('data.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(message)
```

Of course, you don't have to save it as a Python module, you can just save it as text/binary data and read it into your program as an object; maybe with `eval` in case you save it as text.

**EDIT**

Just saw you edited the question. This might be enough for 500,000 keys with 500 items each.